# Website based on ASP.NET IIS Authentication

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am building a website based on ASP.NET IIS. There is a configuration file called web.config.
I can configure the authentication there. The option is "forms ; Windows ; None ".
My question is after set these configuration options, how can user log into this website. Where will the users enter username and password?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly go here and do your homework:

[ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx)

But...

If you use Windows auth then the browser will prompt for credentials - which need to be defined on the server.

If you use forms auth then you need to have a form (!) into which you enter your credentials which you then validate and, post validation, setup an auth cookie.

This is a certain amount of work... so Microsoft offer tools, in the box, to do most of this for you...